# Can a Twinned Hex be targeted at or moved onto a single creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic

In light of the recent Sorcerer nerf w/ Draconic Bloodline + Scorching ray I went in search of a damage boost. I figure Twinned Spell (PHB, p. 102) + Hex (PHB, p. 251) is a good combo.

(Note that Hex can only target a single creature at any level, so it should work with Twinned Spell.)

My plan is to target both on one guy when casting, then I spend two bonus action, over two turns, moving each Hex over to the BBEG.

Does this work? Can I move Twinned Hexes onto a single creature?

Addendum: What would the effects be of a Twinned Enhanced Ability, targeting different attributes given that spells don't stack.

Comment: Can I ask what the recent nerf is re: Scorching Ray?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## This doesn't work

You *can* move two Hexes onto a single creature, but you shouldn't bother.

The problem is that [Hex doesn't stack with itself](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/07/28/twin-hex/) — spells in general don't stack with themselves (*PHB*, p. 205). Since it's the same source, only the largest of the effects of the two Hexes apply to the BBEG. You might as well not bother, and move the extra Hex onto a different target.

(Note that you *can't* target the same creature with the original Twinned Hex, because a Twinned Spell requires a second target to work, per its description. But that's really a minor problem compared to the no-stacking issue.)

Comment: "Only the largest effect"- so while the extra damage will not stack, you will put both disadvantages (if they are different) on the BBEG?

Comment: @Axios_Verum The effects can't be different because the spell only lets you choose an ability to affect once, and twinning doesn't give you a second casting of the spell, it only gives you a second target for the *same* spell.

Answer (score 5):

You can't put them both on the same person initially, as Twinned Spell indicates "a second creature."

If you kill the second creature the Hex is on, you can move the other Hex to the guy you already have a Hex on.

However, it won't affect him double due to the Combining Magical Effects rule on p.205.

You could argue "well, it's not a second casting of Hex, it's the same casting, so the wording of this section lets me weasel into double dipping."  But I don't think that's the intent, and I certainly wouldn't allow it.